# Django/JQuery: can't stop Django form submission with JQuery (preventDefault(), etc. not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to do some simple client-side validation because my form is really simple and just needs to know if all of its fields have been filled out.

Here is the relevant part of the template:

```
{% block content %}
 <form id="location_form" action="{% url "mountain_results" %}" method="GET">
    <h2>Enter your location</h2>
    <input id="location_autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" name="address"
    onFocus="geoLocate()" type="text"></input>

    <h2>Enter your maximum drive time</h2>
    <input name="drive_time"
    placeholder="Enter your maximum drive time (hours)" type="text"></input>

    <h2>Are you shredding today or tomorrow?</h2>
    <select name="shred_day">
        <option value="today">Today</option>
        <option value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Find me snow</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the relevant part of the JS:

```
$('#location_form').on('submit', function(event) {
    alert('dude you totally clicked');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Interestingly, the alert doesn't even fire, so it feels like the event handler isn't even being triggered. Any thoughts? As you can see, I tried both commonly used methods of preventing the default event from firing to no avail.

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('submit', '#location_form', function (event) {
        alert('dude you totally clicked');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});`

Comment: Are you sure that your js functions are loaded? Try to add an alert at the root of your function just to be sure because your code seems to be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onsubmit` event handler to validate the form.I have kep the `action` attribute empty for demo. You can add it along with `onsubmit`. Also is there any specific reason to for `GET` method.
Here is a snippet.

HTML

```
<form id="location_form" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return _validateForm()">
    <h2>Enter your location</h2>
    <input id="location_autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" name="address"
    onFocus="geoLocate()" type="text"></input>

    <h2>Enter your maximum drive time</h2>
    <input name="drive_time"
    placeholder="Enter your maximum drive time (hours)" type="text"></input>

    <h2>Are you shredding today or tomorrow?</h2>
    <select name="shred_day">
        <option value="today">Today</option>
        <option value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Find me snow</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
function _validateForm(){
 alert('dude you totally clicked');
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j5gakdvx/2/).Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another approach. Change

```
<button type="submit">Find me snow</button>
```

With

```
<button id="submit_form">Find me snow</button>
```

and add following JavaScript code

```
$('#submit_form').click(function(){
    if(for_is_valid()){
       $('#location_form').submit();
    }
    else{
       alert('Your message');
    }
});
```

Hope this will work.